# I need to know specific keyword who describes all room related services

Tags: prepositions

Could anyone help me to find out specific keyword for all room related services like light facilities, water facilities, gas facilities and many more.

Comment: Do you mean utilities? An example sentence and more context would help (and prevent close votes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Household facilities